# how to display the search results on same page using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am really new to jQuery Mobile. I want to display the search results on same page using jquery mobile.

In search If I type Bangalore it will hit database and result will display in same page.
[here](http://m.allrecipes.com/search) is an example demo.

I need to implement same way using html+Ajax+Servlet

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. ListView with filter option enabled
2. Using third party library

### Using ListView

ListView has a built in feature that will let you auto filter the contents of the ListView. Its much convenient if you have less data and data readily available at one shot.

You have to set following attribute true in your `<ul>` tag

```
data-filter="true"
```

Here is an example at [Live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/HHfZk/)

You can read the [documentation here](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/listviews/)

### Using library

Andy Mathews has written an [awesome library](http://andymatthews.net/read/2012/03/27/jQuery-Mobile-Autocomplete-now-available) that you can use to do auto searches within the same page.

Its more suitable for complex searches that uses the `xhr` or other type of web services, sockets etc.

You can check out [the demo here](http://andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/).

Comment: In search If I type Bangalore it will hit database and result will display in same page.[link](http://m.allrecipes.com/search) here is an example demo.

I need to implement same way using html+Ajax+Servlet

Please help me.

Comment: You can create a text input and when user types do the web service call and fill a custom listview below.